# "Weights of a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$." What does the picture mean?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathfrak h$ a Cartan subalgebra.  Let $f: \mathfrak g \rightarrow \textrm{End}(V)$ be a representation of $\mathfrak g$.  For $\lambda \in \mathfrak h^{\ast}$, let

$$V_{\lambda} = \{v \in V : f(H)v = \lambda(H)v \textrm{ for all } H \in \mathfrak h \}$$

be the *weight space* of $\lambda$.  The nonzero elements of a weight space are called *weight vectors*.

The following picture is from the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_(representation_theory).  It is captioned, "Example of the weights of a representation of the Lie algebra $\textrm{sl($3,\mathbb{C}$)}$.

[image]

I don't understand what the picture is getting at.  I think this representation is the differential of the adjoint representation $\textrm{Ad}: \textrm{SL}_{3,\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \textrm{GL}( \textrm{Lie}(\textrm{SL}_{3,\mathbb{C}}))$.  I feel like I should know this (or maybe I already know this).  I have a decent understanding of reductive groups over algebraically closed fields, so perhaps I can relate the picture to what I know about that somehow.

Comment: I am on my phone, so this will be the short version. Each arrow corresponds to the action of an element in a root space. The circled dot is the highest weight, so we start from there and apply those arrows corresponding to negative roots. Those dots with a $2$ are those you can get to in two different ways.

Comment: (and, completing what Tobias was saying) they are therefore weight spaces which are two-dimensional.

Comment: I can see that there are two different ways to get to the weight labeled with 2 located in the upper part of the figure. However there does seem I think 3 different possible paths starting from the highest weight to get to the weight labeled with 2 located in the lower part of the figure. I don't understand how the method works. Can someone explain a bit please?